# watermark generated using pillow overriting the whole page in PyPDF2

Tags: python, pdf, python-imaging-library, pypdf

Watermark a `.pdf` page with a text watermark in python using `PyPDF2` and `Pillow`.

**Approach Explored**

Creating a blank image using pillow using `Image.new()` drawing text (watermark) on it using `ImageDraw.Draw()` and saving it using `.save()` as a `PDF`

Using `PdfFileReader()` reading the watermark file and the file to watermark looping over the imput file to merge the watermark and pages of the file using `.merge_page()` writing the final pdf using `PdfFilerWriter()` and `.addPage()`

**Error Encountered**

Repeatedly prints the last page of the input page without the watermark

here is the code:

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
from PyPDF2 import  PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter, PdfReader
"""
Algorithm to add watermark to pdf
"""
pdf_file = "1.pdf"

reader = PdfReader(pdf_file)
dim = reader.pages[0].mediabox
width, height = dim[2], dim[3]
message = f"name \n{id}"
font = ImageFont.truetype("arial.ttf", size=20)
img = Image.new("RGB", (width, height), color="white")
img_draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
text_width, text_height = img_draw.textsize(message, font=font)
xText = (width - text_width) / 2
yText = (height - text_height) / 2
img_draw.text((xText, yText), message, font=font, fill="#bbbbbb", align="center")
img = img.rotate(angle=45, center=(width/2, height/2), fillcolor="white")

img.save('result.png')
img.save('result.pdf', format='PDF')

merged = "merged1.pdf"
watermark = "result.pdf"
with open(pdf_file, "rb") as input_file, open(watermark, "rb") as watermark_file:
    input_pdf = PdfFileReader(input_file)
    watermark_pdf = PdfFileReader(watermark_file)
    output = PdfFileWriter()
    for i in range(input_pdf.getNumPages()):
        watermark_page = watermark_pdf.getPage(0)
        pdf_page = input_pdf.getPage(i)
        watermark_page.merge_page(pdf_page)
        output.addPage(watermark_page)
    with open(merged, "wb") as merged_file:
        output.write(merged_file)
```

Comment: Which version of PyPDF2 did you use? Can you try again with the latest version?